# Ramda: whereAny?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm using Ramda as my functional programming helper library to build a React app.

I'm trying to build myself `whereAny`. Ramda exposes [`where`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#where) which checks if *every* prop it is given satisfies the respective predicate.

I want to build a function that accepts an array of keys, an object and a search term and if any of the keys (which values are strings) includes the search term it should return `true`. If not it should return `false`.

Here is my current workaround:

```
export const whereAny = keys => obj => searchTerm =>
  R.any(
    R.pipe(
      R.toLower,
      R.includes(R.toLower(searchTerm))
    ),
    R.values(R.pick(keys, obj))
  );
export const contactNameIncludesSearchValue = whereAny(['firstName', 'lastName']);
```

As you can see I use it to see if some values of a contact include the search term (IRL I use more than just `firstName` and `lastName`).

My question is how can you build such a `whereAny` function? I looked into the [Ramda cookbook](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook) and on Google and couldn't find a recipe for `whereAny`.

The problem with my workaround (apart from the fact that it's probably not optimal) is that you can't specify different functions just like in `where`. So ideally my api would look like this:

```
const pred = searchValue => R.whereAny({
  a: R.includes(searchValue),
  b: R.equals(searchValue),
  x: R.gt(R.__, 3),
  y: R.lt(R.__, 3)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```js
const fromPair = R.apply(R.objOf);

const whereFromPair = R.compose(R.where, fromPair);

const whereAny = R.compose(R.anyPass, R.map(whereFromPair), R.toPairs);
```

Just [tested it](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20fromPair%20%3D%20R.apply%28R.objOf%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20whereFromPair%20%3D%20R.compose%28R.where%2C%20fromPair%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20whereAny%20%3D%20R.compose%28R.anyPass%2C%20R.map%28whereFromPair%29%2C%20R.toPairs%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20pred%20%3D%20searchValue%20%3D%3E%20whereAny%28%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%20R.includes%28searchValue%29%2C%0A%20%20b%3A%20R.equals%28searchValue%29%2C%0A%20%20x%3A%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log%28%22This%20should%20be%20logged.%22%29%3B%20return%20R.gt%28x%2C%203%29%3B%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20y%3A%20x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log%28%22This%20shouldn%27t%20be%20logged.%22%29%3B%20return%20R.lt%28x%2C%203%29%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28pred%28%22hello%22%29%28%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20b%3A%20%22hola%22%2C%20x%3A%204%2C%20y%3A%203%20%7D%29%29%3B%0A) and it works.

Comment: Note that the `fromPair` here can also be written `R.apply(R.objOf)`.

Comment: did not down-vote but I will remark this computes all predicates before checking if one of them passes

Comment: @user633183 No. It short-circuits just as expected.

Comment: @user633183 I edited my test case to show that it indeed does short-circuit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should curry your functions using Ramda's [`curry`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry).

Why?

With this form of currying, you *have to* call it this way and this way only:

```
const abc = a => b => c => a + b + c;
abc(1)(2)(3); // 6
```

Whereas with this form you are more flexible:

```
const abc = curry((a, b, c) => a + b + c);
abc(1, 2, 3); // 6
abc(1, 2)(3); // 6
abc(1)(2)(3); // 6
```

Also note that Ramda functions tend to accept the data it operates on as the last parameter:

> Ramda functions are automatically curried. This allows you to easily build up new functions from old ones simply by not supplying the final parameters.
>
> The parameters to Ramda functions are arranged to make it convenient for currying. The data to be operated on is generally supplied last.
>
> The last two points together make it very easy to build functions as sequences of simpler functions, each of which transforms the data and passes it along to the next. Ramda is designed to support this style of coding.

Cf [project homepage](https://ramdajs.com/)

I think we can still use this approach to solve your problem:

```js
const whereAny = curry((keys, search, obj) =>
  compose(includes(search), props(keys))
    (obj));
    
const whereNameIsFoo = whereAny(['firstName', 'lastName'], 'foo');

console.log(whereNameIsFoo({firstName: 'john', lastName: 'foo'}));
console.log(whereNameIsFoo({firstName: 'bar', lastName: 'baz'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {curry, compose, flip, includes, props} = R;</script>
```

Comment: You're going off at a tangent to the OP's question. You haven't shown how to implement `whereAny` the way the OP wants. Instead, you're talking about the advantages of auto-currying.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I like your approach a lot and will use it instead of my workaround.

Comment: this also gives the early exit i would expect

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use the answer from Aadit M Shah, but you might also model it on the [implementation of `where`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/where.js)

```js
const whereAny = R.curry((spec, testObj) => {
  for (let [key, fn] of Object.entries(spec)) {
    if (fn(testObj[key])) {return true}
  }
  return false
})

const pred = searchValue => whereAny({
  a: R.includes(searchValue),
  b: R.equals(searchValue),
  x: R.gt(R.__, 3),
  y: R.lt(R.__, 3)
});

console.log(pred("hello")({ a: [], b: "hola", x: 3, y: 2 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: this gives the early exit i would expect

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but Ramda has recently released `whereAny`.

The docs are at https://ramdajs.com/docs/#whereAny